# Автоматическая авторизация на сайте

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Заходим на сайт под логином и паролем, потом закрываем браузер. Снова открываем браузер и сайт - авторизоваться не нужно. Понятное дело, что логин и пароль запомнил браузер и куда-то записал.

1. Как правильно назвать вышеописанное? (для дальнейшего гугления)
2. Может ли кто подсказать или привести пример простейшего запоминания логина и пароля сайтом?
    Писать саму регистрацию умею, вот остался последний штрих.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Все про куки и больше](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/cookies.php)

Comment: прочитал. попробовал на реальном хостинге. все по инструкции. результат - только ошибки. конечно я могу и написать, что в ошибке, но а толку то? (Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...index.php:4) in ...index.php) можно объяснить про куки как то по другому? форма на сайте, 2 текстбокса, 1 кнопка (авторизация), логин/пасс есть в базе... дальше подскажите?

Comment: @frank - ты с мануалами дружишь? по ответам если судить так ты ждешь когда тебе напишут чтобы заработало.

В большинстве случаев тут напишут в какую сторону двигаться дальше, а вот не всегда напишут код.

Comment: ошибка оказалась в моих действиях. немного не разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Браузер запомнил не логин/пароль а данные сессии, которые записал в cookie. Вот вам и тема для дальнейшего гугления.

Answer (score 0):

Время жизни сессии по умолчанию заканчивается после того как был закрыт браузер, можно продлить это время в секундах

```
session_set_cookie_params(10800);
```

Comment: Да можно, только лучше 60*60*24 =86400
т.е session_set_cookie_params(86400);

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_logged=false;
if(isset($do) && $do=="do_login"){
if(isset($login) && isset($password)){
    $password=@md5($password);
    $db->Query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login='$login' and pass='$password'");
    if($db->RowCount()){
    $row=$db->Row();

    setcookie("user_id",$row->id,time()+28800);
    setcookie("user_password",$password,time()+28800);

    @session_register("user_id");
    @session_register("user_password");
    $_SESSION["user_id"]=$row->id;
    $_SESSION["user_password"]=$password;

    $is_logged=true;
    }
}
}elseif(intval($_SESSION["user_id"]) > 0 && $_SESSION["user_password"]){
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=".intval($_SESSION["user_id"]));
$row=$db->Row(); 
if($_SESSION["user_password"]==$row->pass){
    $is_logged=true;
}else{
    $is_logged=false;
}
}elseif(intval($_COOKIE["user_id"] > 0)){
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=".intval($_COOKIE["user_id"]));
$row=$db->Row();
if($_COOKIE["user_password"]==$row->pass){
    $is_logged=true;
    @session_register("user_id");
    @session_register("user_password");
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row->id;
    $_SESSION['user_password']=$_COOKIE["user_password"];
}else{
    $is_logged=false;
}

}

if(!$is_logged){

setcookie("user_id", "", 0);
setcookie("user_password", "", 0);
$_SESSION["user_id"]=0;
$_SESSION["user_password"]="";

$smarty->display("sitelogin.tpl");

}
```

Вот одно из решений... Кстати зацените уровень безопасности.

Comment: интересное решение. спасибо